# PHP exec, wget download file to specific directory

Tags: php, linux, wget

I'm attempting to download a file with wget using PHP exec to a specific directory and it is not working. No errors are showing either?

Here is my code:

```
$filename = 'test2.mp4';
$source = 'http://example.com/test.mp4';

    var_dump(exec('wget -b -o '.$filename.' '.$source.' -p /home/mywebsite/public_html/assets/videos/ -h 2>&1', $output, $errno), $output, $errno);
```

What did i do wrong in my wget command?

```
-b so download runs in background

-o to rename the file to test2.mp4

-p to download to specific directory
```

How do i solve?

Comment: Have you tested it directly on the command-line without PHP? Does it work in PHP without the -b flag? (Although in that case you could just use file_get_contents() direct in PHP)

Comment: I agree, try removing the `-b` flag. Without actually trying your code, I would think that doing that _might_ cause `exec` to return early which would mean that `$output` would be empty. What is the output of the `var_dump()`? It should be `false` on failure.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of that, I would recommend to try downloading using cURL requests. Try using this:

```
function getFile($fileUrl, $newFileName) {
    $err_msg = '';
    echo "<br>Attempting message download for: $fileUrl <br/>";
    $out = fopen($newFileName, 'wb');

    if ($out == FALSE) {
        print "File not opened <br/>";
        exit;
    }

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $out);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $fileUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_exec($ch);
    echo "<br/>Message: " . !empty(curl_error($ch)) ? curl_error($ch) : "OK!";

    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($out);
}
```